# If $y = \frac{2}{5}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^3+\cdots$, find $y^2+2y$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> If $$y = \frac{2}{5}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^3+\cdots$$ what is $y^2+2y$?

Attempt:

We know that for negative and fractional indices,

$$(1+x)^n = 1 + nx + n(n-1)/2!\cdot x^2 + n(n-1)(n-2)/3!\cdot x^3 + \cdots$$

Rewriting the series in question, we get:

$$\frac{2}{5} \left(1 + \frac{1\cdot3}{2!}\cdot \frac{2}{5}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2+\cdots\right)$$

I know this looks like the binomial expansion above, but I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Familiar with [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

Comment: @Alexey Burdin No, and since I am attempting this problem as an exercise, a solution involving the binomial theorem for negative and fractional indices would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok, then [hint](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+2*k%2B1%2C+k%3D0..n) about simplifying the product in the numerator

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I simplified the sum to $\frac{2}{5} \left(\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac {(2r + 1)!}{r!}\left (\frac{1} {5}\right) ^ r\right) $. What do I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate $y$ using a "well known" binomial series expansion for
$$(1-4x)^{-\frac 12} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}nx^n$$

To see this rewrite the coefficients

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{k} = \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k-1)\cdot 2k}{k\cdot 2k}= \frac 1{2^n}\binom{2n}n$$

So in your case the series becomes

$$y = \sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^n}\binom{2n}n \frac{2^n}{5^n} = \sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{\infty} \binom{2n}n\frac 1{5^n}$$ $$ = \left.\frac 1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right|_{x = \frac 15} = \sqrt 5 - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\frac{2}{5}$:
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}(\prod_{k=1}^{i}(2k-1))$$
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}((2i-1)!!)$$

For $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$, this is the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}-1$

$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}-1$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.8}}-1$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.2}}-1$$
$$y=\sqrt{5}-1$$

$$y^2+2y=(\sqrt{5}-1)^2+2(\sqrt{5}-1)$$
$$y^2+2y=5+1-2\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{5}-2$$
$$y^2+2y=4$$